# Proving Equivalence between Multivariate distributions and Gaussian Bayesian Networks

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, graphical-model, bayesian-network

I am studying Probabilistic Graphical Models by Daphne Koller. In Chap 7, the authors say the following.

[image]

I can't convince myself of the highlighted part. Induction typically has a statement for n, using which you prove a statement for n+1. Given the graphical nature of the problem, I can't formulate what the n case means, and how to increment it to a larger (n+1) case.

For example, consider the graph shown below. Here, $X_1,\dots,X_5$ are jointly normal, and arrows denote linear combinations, so that, $Y = \sum_{i=1}^4 \beta_i X_i$. Now using the "base" case, one can argue that $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,Y$ are jointly normal, and similarly, $X_5,Y,Z$ are jointly normal. But how does one argue that all the variables ($X_is, Y, Z$) are jointly normal?

[image]

Comment: It is by induction because Theorem starts with parents only not the entire network. n would be the nodes.

Comment: I clarified my question further.

Comment: You need a "strong induction" where you assume a statement is true for $n=0,1, \ldots, N$ and show it must be true for $n=N+1.$

Comment: Yes I felt that too. However, I think some other property of gaussian multivariate random variables is needed. In the example I show, how does one go from $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,Y$ are jointly normal and $X_5,Y,Z$ are jointly normal to ($X_is, Y, Z$) are jointly normal?

Comment: Wow! Such a great example of the "it clearly follows" phenomenon. For that exact network, I'd note that $\operatorname P (X_1, \ldots, X_5, Y, Z) = \operatorname P(X_5, Y, Z | X_1, \ldots, X_4) \operatorname P(X_1, \ldots, X_4)$ and use the theorem to show the first term is multivariate normal and then the whole thing clearly is. But to turn that into some kind of induction proof for all networks would require some work. Wonder what others think.